# Why I am not able to access string individual chars using index

Tags: c++, string, c++11

```cpp
string strMap[8] = {"abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqrs", "tuv", "wxyz"};
//string digits received as parameter in function // digits = "234";
```

Accessing it as below:

```cpp
int digitmapIndex = digits[index] - 46;   //index is some int 0,1 etc..
int mapstr_len = strMap[digitmapIndex];
```

or

```cpp
int mapstr_len = strMap[digits[index] - 46];
```

Error:

```
Line 25: Char 13: error: no viable conversion from 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>') to 'int'
        int mapstr_len = strMap[digits[index] - 46];
            ^            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:816:7: note: candidate function
      operator __sv_type() const noexcept
```

Comment: `strMap[digitmapIndex]` is a `std::string` the compiler does not have a way to automatically convert it to an integer.

Comment: By your variable naming did you want: `int mapstr_len = strMap[digitmapIndex].length();`

Comment: Yes ..got it. silly mistake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line makes no sense:

```
int mapstr_len = strMap[digitmapIndex];
```

`strMap[digitmapIndex]` is a `string` object, and cannot be assigned to an `int`.

```
auto temp = strMap[digitmapIndex];
```

From `temp`, you can access its chars by index.